# Eloquent $appends acts strangely in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

am simply trying to include a new attribute to be available in the json response but for some reason am also getting the object relation as well.

```php
// user model
protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $appends = ['role_name'];
protected $hidden  = ['remember_token', 'password'];

public function getRoleNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->role->type;
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
} 

// role model
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

when i use `dd($user);` i get

```json
User {#303
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #appends: array:1 [
    0 => "role_name"
  ]
  #hidden: array:2 [
    0 => "remember_token"
    1 => "password"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "name" => "testing"
    "email" => "email@asd.com"
    "password" => "$2y$10$fogQXhJZm5eoViM38pge1.BmNxY7IFl515zT83.Ks9Uj26kK9T6Im"
    "role_id" => "83eee2e0-8939-48f7-9fbc-1c077e2265e5"
    "id" => "a181fb4b-b65a-47b4-9c72-21ea15c6c5a6"
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-30 20:23:52"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-30 20:23:52"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [
    "name" => "testing"
    "email" => "email@asd.com"
    "password" => "$2y$10$fogQXhJZm5eoViM38pge1.BmNxY7IFl515zT83.Ks9Uj26kK9T6Im"
    "role_id" => "83eee2e0-8939-48f7-9fbc-1c077e2265e5"
    "id" => "a181fb4b-b65a-47b4-9c72-21ea15c6c5a6"
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-30 20:23:52"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-30 20:23:52"
  ]
  ...
}
```

and with `return response()->json(compact('user'));` instead i get

```json
user: {
    created_at: "2017-01-30 20:26:12"
    email:"email@asd.com"
    id:"4b83e031-e8c8-4050-963d-446cb383fb14"
    name:"testing"
    role:{
        created_at:"2016-12-29 10:54:02"
        id:"83eee2e0-8939-48f7-9fbc-1c077e2265e5"
        type:"user"
        updated_at:"2016-12-29 10:54:02"
    }
    role_id:"83eee2e0-8939-48f7-9fbc-1c077e2265e5"
    role_name:"user"
    updated_at:"2017-01-30 20:26:12"
}
```

but what i expect is to only have

```json
user: {
    created_at: "2017-01-30 20:26:12"
    email:"email@asd.com"
    id:"4b83e031-e8c8-4050-963d-446cb383fb14"
    name:"testing"
    role_id:"83eee2e0-8939-48f7-9fbc-1c077e2265e5"
    role_name:"user"
    updated_at:"2017-01-30 20:26:12"
}
```

so am not sure if this is the normal behavior or a bug or maybe am missing something ?

- Laravel version 5.3.30

Comment: How your are fetching $user ?

Comment: this is the returned object of a created user ex.`$user = User::create([...]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is the following

```
public function getRoleNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->role->type;
}
```

The problem here is the when you say `$this->role` it will automatically attached the relationship to the model.  In order to prevent this, you should simply be able to access the method directly, like `$this->role()`.

```
public function getRoleNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->role()->first()->type;
}
```

Comment: first one gave `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$type`, second worked as expected, thanx